# Creating widget like WordPress in custom cms

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to create latest post widgets etc like in WordPress on my custom cms any advice where to start would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Widgets in WordPress are basically objects that can be "hooked" into particular places in a theme. The most similar mechanism in Laravel would be [Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events), I'd say.

Wherever you want a widget to appear in your CMS, you would fire an event, say "WidgetsGoHere", and insert the response(s) from that event into your view.

Then, I'd probably create an [Event Subscriber](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/events#event-subscribers) class for each widget (and probably a base class of Widget from which all widgets could inherit helpful code.) The event subscriber would listen for the WidgetsGoHere event, then build whatever it needed to output—a bunch of HTML, presumably—and return it as a response. The code that fired the event would then output the response.

In WordPress, a theme or plugin registers any widgets it uses as part of the theme or plugin startup code. If you haven't developed plugins or themes for your CMS yet, you may want to add some code (perhaps in "start") to create your widgets and get them listening for events. You can hardcode them to start with, and perhaps move to a more dynamic system once you've got things working.

Here's a very simple worked example. We'll create three "widgets". Start with a standard install of Laravel. Then, edit `app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php` and change the `$listen` variable there as follows:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\WantWidgets' => [
        'App\Handlers\WidgetOne',
        'App\Handlers\WidgetTwo',
        'App\Handlers\WidgetThree',
    ],
];
```

Save that and then run the artisan command `php artisan event:generate`. This will read the configuration we've just provided and create an event called `WantWidgets` and three different event listeners, which will be our three widgets. You should be able to see the new classes in `app\Events` and `app\Handlers`.

Then, change `WelcomeController.php` so that the `WelcomeController` index page fires the event and passes the responses it gets back to its view:

```
public function index()
{
    $widgets = Event::fire(new \App\Events\WantWidgets);
    return view('welcome')->with('widgets', $widgets);
}
```

In the view (`resources\views\welcome.blade.php`) take the "widgets" you're now passed and output them:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($widgets as $widget)
        <li>{{ $widget}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

If you fire up the web app now, you'll find that you don't get very much interesting stuff out, because the "widgets" are currently outputting nothing. You should at least see three list item dots.

Now, change the "widgets" to return something. For example, edit `app\Handlers\WidgetOne.php` so that its `handle` method returns a simple string:

```
public function handle(WantWidgets $event)
{
    return "I could be a widget when I grow up";
}
```

And when you refresh the page, you should see that string as one of the list items.

This is similar to the way the WordPress widget system works—at the point in the page you want widgets to appear, you fire an event. Widgets are "registered" to that event and "draw" themselves, outputting HTML to the page at that point.

That should get you started. Virtually everything about this can be improved. For example, your widgets might use their own blade template to render their HTML into a string and return that.

Comment: Thanks matt any simple example would be great

Comment: @TerryLin Given that that's a very different matter, I think you should probably just ask a new question.

Comment: @MattGibson do you have any started project where is it implemented the way you described here or something similar?